# Как сохранить json в mongodb с помощью spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Есть пример кода, как можно его переделать под запись json?

```
 package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class Customer {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}


package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}

package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста ваш вопрос, если вопрос состоит в том что Customer её сохраняется,  то добавьте к вашему классу Customer аннотацию @Document.

Comment: Это пример записи java класса. Задача состоит в том чтобы подобным образом я мог записать в базу пришедший мне json

Answer (score 0):

У MongoTemplate есть метод executeCommand();

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

class YourClass{
public void someMethod(){
        String s = "your raw mongo query";
        DBObject query = (DBObject) JSON.parse(s);
        mongoTemplate.executeCommand(query);
    }
}
```

Подробнее здесь:
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mongodb.CommandResult

Также есть библиотека Jongo, в принципе в этом ответе достаточно инфы:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623589/java-excute-mongodb-raw-query

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь сделать тоже самое средствами spring, используя тот же crud? Мне дали задание - "разобраться как спринг работает с монго, написать простой тест, который пишет в базу заданный json" , но я немогу найти примеров использования спринга.

Comment: @ИльяХирный что именно вы имеете ввиду под crud? Консоль монго?