# java mongodb distinct

Tags: java, mongodb

1) Прямой запрос к БД выглядит так:

```
db.getCollection('collection').distinct("body.uniq_value_id");
```

- получим все уникальные значения uniq_value_id.

2) Непосредственно на Java есть такая реализация:

```
            List uniqlist = collection.distinct("body.uniq_value_id"); 

            for (int i = 0; i < uniqlist.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println(varTextB.get(i));
            }
```

- тут получим ТОЖЕ все уникальные значения `uniq_value_id` В КОНСОЛЬ.

3) Дальше есть запрос в формате:

```
db.tracking.distinct("body.uniq_value_name", {"body.uniq_value_id":"some_id1"});
```

- этот запрос в свою очередь отобразит все уникальные значения `body.uniq_value_name` для записей где `body.uniq_value_id` будет иметь значение `some_id1`.

Вопрос - как использовать в Java подобные запросы? 
Вопрос актуальный так как синтаксис запросов может быть структурно сложным, например:

```
db.collection.find({"body.uniq_value_name":"some_name1","body.uniq_other":{$in:[/active.*=.*yes/i]}}).pretty();
```

Comment: Если вы используете spring-data то уже есть много ответов
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639348/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B2-mongodb-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-spring/639468#639468

Comment: Спасибо за линки, удалось реализовать через Jongo.

Comment: Jongo/Aggregation: 

`List<String> result = collection.distinct("body.uniq_value_name").query("{body.uniq_value_id:'some_id1'}").as(String.class);`

- Кому интересно - все довольно подробно описано тут: [Jongo about](http://jongo.org/#querying)